# Netbeans local variable table greyed-out

Tags: java, netbeans

While debugging in Netbeans 6.5 on Linux all the values in the type and value columns are grey out and only readable if selected.  Since you can't select the text in type column, it is not possible to know what the types are, a big problem for exceptions.

There does not appear to be any option for changing the colours and a fair amount of Googleing has not yielded any answers.

I'm running NetBeans IDE 6.5 (Build 090226) on Java 1.6.0_16 on Linux 2.6.30.10 (Fedora I believe).

[example http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/3585/localvars.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/3585/localvars.png)

Comment: I hope this question is not too too tech-supporty.

Comment: I would suggest using Netbeans 6.8, IMHO there is a huge difference between 6.5 and 6.8. Had no problems installing the Netbeans 6.8 bundle (a packaged .sh install, no .deb) on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=157300) in NetBeans 6.5. It doesn't look there is a patch yet, but the problem is fixed in newer versions of NetBeans 6.7+